# How to add Sections and Subheader in android material drawer Recyclerview items?

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I have used the following tutorial to implement material design drawer.

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

But i want to add sections in the drawer after 2 items. How to make the recyclerview display sections and subheaders?

Comment: Have you took a look at `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` ?It is what you really need.

Comment: What you have to do is enclose menu items of the drawer in `<group .../>` to show the separator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You better use the [design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) to do this.
specifically `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` class
Checkout the following links for more

- [Tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer)
- [Github sample](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)

Some code snippets from sample:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <include layout="@layout/include_list_viewpager"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And menu shown on drawer will have a separator at the end of the first menu group.
drawer_view.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:title="Home" />
        ....
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_discussion"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
            android:title="Discussion" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Sub items">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
                android:title="Sub item 1" />
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
                android:title="Sub item 2" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: Is there any sample i can use in Eclipse? The sample link u have added is using gradle build! Give me link to any Sample or something like a template that i can use in my application? thank you in advance..

Comment: If you have imported  design support library to your project and you are using the latest sdk tools, you can simply do it in Eclipse, no difference! Just copy the above `activity_main.xml` to your layout folder and `drawer_view.xml` from the same sample.

Comment: Is there any way to add a separation line without the title? Just like the navigation drawer in Inbox.

Comment: @jmunoz if you replace <item android:title="Sub items"> with <item> you will not see the title.